# Retrieving the element above in a matrix (Python)

Tags: python, list, matrix

I have a matrix of the form:

```
    matrix = [[1,0,1],[0,1,0],[1,1,0]]
```

(In my actual problem it is a much bigger one, but I'll keep it simple. What's important is that countains only zeros and ones.)

For every element in the matrix I want to assign a value to the variable 'alive', representing the amount of ones that are surrounding it. For the horizontals, I did it like this:

```
    alive = matrix[i+1] + matrix[i-1]
```

But now I also want to take the elements above (and underneath, but that can be done the same way) into account.

How can I retrieve the element right above the element I'm counting the ones for?

Comment: Are you programming Minesweeper?  :)

Comment: As a side note, I don't think that `matrix[i+1] + matrix[i-1]` will work ... maybe `matrix[j][i+1] + matrix[j][i-1]` ...

Comment: And, accordingly to traverse the other way: `matrix[j + 1][i]` and `matrix[j - 1][i]`.

Comment: @mgilson No, it's probably [Life](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life)! :)

Comment: @mgilson, Sounds like Life.

Comment: @MarkTolonen -- Never programmed that one ... though I've heard the reference before.  Too bad.  I like Minesweeper :)

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to program Life, an assignment for school :) matrix[i+1] etc worked for a matrix with one row, more rows won't work :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses! All of the above seem like good examples of different ways to handle the problem. But the assignment was given as an excercise on for-in loops and if/else structures, so I don't think we are allowed to use, for example, numpy functions.

Answer (score 2):

I usually like to simply access to multidimensional lists using something like this:

```
matrix = [[1,0,1],[0,1,0],[1,1,0]]
valatpos = dict()
for row, inner in enumerate(matrix):
  for col, val in enumerate(inner):
    valatpos[row,col] = val
```

Then, when comparing, you call this to get a value, moving up or down rows or columns in any combination.

```
valatpos[i + 1, j] # Below
valatpos[i - 1, j] # Above
valatpos[i, j - 1] # Left
valatpos[i, j + 1] # Right
valatpos[i + 1, j + 1] # Below, Right
```

Which I prefer over:

```
matrix[i + 1][j]
```

Comment: The change is minor, a comma traded for a couple braces, but it _feels_ easier to work with.  It's also effective for deeper nesting, when working in 3 or more dimensions.

Comment: Alternatively, if your list contains elements of the same type (like the integers above), you can use numpy arrays which have this kind of indexing built in. (Provided using a package which is not part of the standard Python distribution is OK).

Answer (score 1):

You could calculate alive for the entire matrix using numpy's array constructs:

```
import numpy as np

 # Your matrix defined as numpy array:
 matrix = np.array([[ 1, 0, 1 ], [ 0, 1, 1 ], [ 0, 0, 1 ]])

 # Get the size of the matrix
 nn = matrix.shape[0]

 # Create alive matrix by summing the four neighboring fields:
 alive = np.fromfunction(lambda i, j: matrix[(i+1)%nn, j] + matrix[(i-1)%nn, j]
    + matrix[i, (j+1)%nn] + matrix[i, (j-1)%nn], (nn, nn), dtype=int)
```

Using numpy arrays you can access the elements as `alive[i, j]` directly.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like the following is what you are looking for:

```
def get_alive(matrix):
    empty = [0]*(len(matrix[0])+2)
    temp = [empty] + [[0]+row+[0] for row in matrix] + [empty]
    def count(i, j):
        return (sum(temp[i-1][j-1:j+2]) + temp[i][j-1] + temp[i][j+1] +
                sum(temp[i+1][j-1:j+2]))
    rows = range(1, len(temp)-1)
    cols = range(1, len(temp[0])-1)
    return [[count(i, j) for j in cols] for i in rows]
```

Example:

```
>>> import pprint
>>> matrix = [[1,0,1],[0,1,0],[1,1,0]]
>>> alive = get_alive(matrix)
>>> pprint.pprint(matrix, width=20)
[[1, 0, 1],
 [0, 1, 0],
 [1, 1, 0]]
>>> pprint.pprint(alive, width=20)
[[1, 3, 1],
 [4, 4, 3],
 [2, 2, 2]]
```